# Missing required parameters for [Route: productbyid] [URI: pages/{$idtype}/productbyid]

Tags: php, laravel

I am missing the required parameters for this route:

productbyid URI:

```
pages/{$idtype}/productbyid
```

The view is at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\resources\views\layout\main.blade.php
```

My route:

```
Route::get('pages/{$idtype}/productbyid','Controller@getspbyid') -> name('productbyid');
```

My Controller :

```
function getspbyid($idtype){
  $getsp = Model::find($idtype)->get();
  return view('pages.productbyid',(['getsp'=>$getsp]));
}
```

My Main.blade

```
<ul>
                        <li><a href="{{route('products')}}">Woman</a>                   
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($show as $shows)
                                <li><a href="{{route('productbyid')}}"
                                      {{$shows['name']}}</a></li>                                   
                                @endforeach 
                            </ul>
                        </li>                                                           
                        <li><a href="./products.html">Man</a></li>          
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need $ sign in Route, also you have to call your Controller, something like this:

```
Route::get('pages/{idtype}/productbyid','ProductController@getspbyid')->name('productbyid');
```

To retrieve data by find method dont need use get method, and you must use your modelname instead Model class

```
$getsp = Product::find($idtype);
```

In return statement dont need parentheses

```
return view('pages.productbyid',['getsp'=>$getsp]);
```

Also you sent getsp to `pages.productbyid` but in your page used `$shows` in foreach, while you didnt pass such this variable

Comment: so what should i do with foreach ??? i just want to query my menu list @@~ and link to productbyid but it's not working